# Where does X-Men Origins: Wolverine leave off?

Tags: comics, marvel, wolverine

At the end of Wolverine's origin movie, he is in a bar in Tokyo, with no memory of the Weapon X programme. Does this correspond to any particular story arc in the comics; the ending of one of the beginning?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Japanese Bar ending/stinger does not necessarily lead into any particular storyline as he has spent a lot of time in Japan. That said, the most famous storyline taking place in Japan is the one where he falls in love with Mariko Yashida, the daughter of a crime lord and the half-sister of the Silver Samurai.

The next Wolverine movie was last reported to be taking place in Japan. When Aronofsky was still attached as the director he said it would be more of a "one-off" than a sequel - implying that it *could* be a prequel (in terms of timeline) instead. Since then, James Mangold has taken over as director,  but there has been no word (that I've read, at least) regarding any changes to the story or script. Obviously, most Wolverine fans are hoping for the Mariko storyline to be adapted for the next film.

Comment: Consider editing that, now that the movie's out :)